# Strange bug where function doesn't get evaluated at all

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, outlook, vsto

I have this strange situation where I have an Outlook VSTO add-in written in c# targeting Outlook 2007 and 2010. The add-in works fine in 2007 environment. It also works fine in debug mode with Outlook 2010 in Visual Studio (2010) when I press start. However, once I deploy to UAT one of the functions doesn't get evaluated at all.

One of the functions is

```
private static bool HTTPTransmitEmailItem(string username, string email_file_name)
        {
            // DEBUG
            Utils.LogDebug("Got into HTTPTransmitEmailItem");
            try
            {
                Stopwatch timer = new Stopwatch();
                timer.Start();
                try
                {
                    Utils.LogDebug("Msg saved as : " + full_file_name_and_path);

                    if (HTTPPostDataToEP(username, temp_path, email_file_name))
                    {
                        File.Delete(full_file_name_and_path);
                        return true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Utils.LogWarn("Trans Fail, Storing for later sending. " + email_file_name);
                        //if need start resend timer
                        TransmitFailed();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                         Utils.HandleException("OFE HHTP Ex", ex);

   

TransmitFailed();


                }

                timer.Stop();
                Utils.LogDebug("Email File Thread took " + timer.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString() + "(ms)");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }
            return false;
        }
```

The culprit is the part:

```
if (HTTPPostDataToEP(username, temp_path, email_file_name))
                        {
                            File.Delete(full_file_name_and_path);
                            return true;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Utils.LogWarn("Trans Fail, Storing for later sending. " + email_file_name);
                            //if need start resend timer
                            TransmitFailed();
                        }
```

The application never enters the method `HTTPPostDataToEP`... The method definition is

```
private static bool HTTPPostDataToEP(string username, string path, string name)
        {
            // DEBUG
            Utils.LogDebug("Got into HTTPPostDataToEP");
            try
            {
                var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
                content.Add(new StringContent(username), "userAddress");
                content.Add(new StreamContent(File.Open(path + name, FileMode.Open)), "msg", name);
                // DEBUG
                Utils.LogDebug("In Line 174 in OutlookTransmitRaw");
                var client = new HttpClient();
                HttpResponseMessage result = client.PostAsync(Utils.configEndPoint, content).Result;
                // DEBUG
                Utils.LogDebug("In Line 178 in OutlookTransmitRaw. Result is " + result);
                if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    Utils.LogDebug("Msg Transmit Response : " + result.ToString());
                else
                    Utils.LogInfo("Msg Fail Transmit Response: " + result.ToString());

                return result.IsSuccessStatusCode;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception("Failed to dispatch email to API. Caused by ", ex);
            }
        }
```

The application doesn't raise any exception. It simply walks pass that `if` block and executes `Utils.LogDebug("Email File Thread took " + timer.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString() + "(ms)");` This only happens when I publish the project and install it using set.exe file. In debug mode it works as expected...

Comment: Hard to know exactlyy the reason, your empty catch does not help much. Maybe your second LogDebug `Utils.LogDebug("Msg saved as : " + full_file_name_and_path);` call fails? It could explain why the next line is not executed. Write a proper exception handling.

Comment: Anything that indicates that `Utils.HandleException("OFE HHTP Ex", ex);
TransmitFailed();` was or was not executed? Unless one of those methods throws another exception, you are still swallowing your exception and moving on as if nothing happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The empty `catch` block would explain your problem: an exception is raised and you simply ignore that and happily carry on.

I could imaging something going wrong with file permissions after you deploy your solution, for instance. But whatever goes wrong gets swallowed up and you'll never hear about it...

Either throw from that catch block, or log something before you throw, but blindly ignoring exceptions like this is never a good idea. Something goes wrong, you get an exception with information, and you refuse to look at it.

Wrong:

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
}
```

Weird and useless:

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw;
}
```

Often useful:

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Logger.Log(ex);
    throw;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, that catch block isn't empty. I removed it for brevity. The line about time taken for the thread right before that catch block gets executed and printed

Comment: You could at least hint at _what_ is in there and indicate how you know that no exception is thrown...

Comment: Sorry about that. Actually that time taken debug line gets printed right before the catch block.

Comment: @swdon I was actually talking about the catch block _before_ that debug line.

Comment: @swdon write exception handling code (logging) in all your catch blocks to get more info on what did fail.

Comment: @oerkelens, you were right, there was an exception thrown in the catch block: System.Net.Http assembly or dependency missing. Thank you!